# monitor renaming a table in a sql server database with trigger

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger, table-rename

I have a trigger that logs on changes to the metadata of tables in a database. 
it saves the logs in another table called *tblMonitorChange*. 
**When i rename a table no triggers is generated.**

this is the trigger :

```
USE ReportServer
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER trgMonitorChange
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE , RENAME_TABLE
AS
set nocount on
declare @EventType varchar(100)
declare @SchemaName varchar(100)
declare @ObjectName varchar(100)
declare @ObjectType varchar(100)
SELECT 
 @EventType = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(max)')  
,@SchemaName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')  
,@ObjectName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
,@ObjectType = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(max)')   
-- Is the default schema used 
if @SchemaName = ' ' select @SchemaName = default_schema_name from sys.sysusers u join sys.database_principals p 
                        on u.uid = p.principal_id  where u.name = CURRENT_USER
insert into tblMonitorChange 
      select @EventType, @SchemaName, @ObjectName, @ObjectType, getdate(), SUSER_SNAME()
```

this is a sample output on 1) creating TestTable, 2)renaming it to TestTable2 and then 3) adding a column to it.

```
EventType      SchemaName   ObjectName  ObjectType  EventDate      

CREATE_TABLE    dbo          TestTable   TABLE      2017-11-01 10:55:44.590 
 ALTER_TABLE    dbo          TestTable2  TABLE      2017-11-01 14:36:07.543
```

But renaming has not been logged.

So how can i monitor renaming the table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace Rename_table event with RENAME event? Below Codes working properly

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trigger_alter ON DATABASE 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE,RENAME
AS 

    DECLARE @ddltriggerxml  XML;
    SELECT @ddltriggerxml  = EVENTDATA();
    SELECT @ddltriggerxml;

GO

CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT)
go
sp_rename 'test_new','test'
```